# What is the point of sourceSets in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Per the docs and what I've read online sourceSets are a logical grouping of files that should be packaged together. When you specify a sourceSet you can also specify a class path and other associated attributes. But could someone explain what is the purpose of a sourceSet? What basic problem does it solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older projects (with Apache ANT builds for example) do not necessarily adhere to a standardized file structure.

`sourceSets` allows for conversion of these projects without rearranging the file structure. This can keep the original project management, or any scripts (possibly used in deployment or whatever) -- that rely on the file structure remaining the same -- intact.

For a new project, it makes very little sense to change the sourceSets, and it is better to adhere to the standard.

Comment: but why would a build system care whether the file structure changes?

Comment: @JeremyFisher By default Gradle will look for your sourcefiles under `src/main/java`. If your source files are there and you change the path in `sourceSet` Gradle will not find the files. The same goes for any other build tools that do not use that same path. To accommodate these projects Gradle just offers an easy way to change this path. Why doesn't it just scan for source files everywhere? Idk, probably for efficiency, and for a clear way to know what the exact `group name` is if any (the path under `/java`, eg: `com/organisation`).

Comment: thanks, the comment clarified it for me